# Remove message after discord webhook was posted

Tags: python, discord, bots, webhooks

I did a suggestions bot where you post a  suggestion and the bot posts it inside a webhook so you can react if this suggestion is good or bad! Now I try that the bot deletes the first message which was posted by the user so I only have the webhook left. I was thinking deleting it with the message id but I had only issues with that. I hope someone can help me.

```
import os
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook,DiscordEmbed

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith(''):

        message_text = message.content.strip()

        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='https://discord.com/api/webhooks/826534186978115645/JIQyWHFs3-7XBdmcnsWIWQ2xKSW20v7-Nu18MUFrWnLiOZr59zDaYFYNB')

        #create embed object for webhook
        embed = DiscordEmbed(title="New Suggestion by {.author}".format(message),  color='25211F')

        # set thumbnail
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1335666008158318593/rzi-99qX_400x400.jpg')

        # set footer
        embed.set_footer(text='CloverPings', icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1257792878962712583/uVn8Upko_400x400.jpg')

        # set timestamp (default is now)
        embed.set_timestamp()

        # add fields to embed
        embed.add_embed_field(name='Suggestion', value=message_text)



        # add embed object to webhook
        webhook.add_embed(embed)
        response = webhook.execute()
        await message.add_reaction("")
        await message.add_reaction("")



client.run("Mytoken")
```

Comment: You can try to define the user input and delete that, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: yes but how is the question :)